# Can't edit category description with DevDemon Editor 3.2.3

Tags: devdemon, editor

We're using Editor 3.2.3 on an EE2 site to nicely format category descriptions. When we try to edit the category description from an edit entry page, however, it can't be edited. [Here's a gif to demonstrate.](http://d.pr/i/clnl)

Is this normal/expected behavior?

Comment: in EE 2.10, the whole category editor isn't triggering Editor. What EE version is that?

Comment: It's EE v2.10.1